# Liquid parsing date incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, date, liquid

I have a file `standard_en.html` with the following code:

```
    <td class="title">Date of Birth</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      {{ meta/birth_date | date: "%m/%d/%Y" }}
    </td>
```

This is outputting `08/18/1970`, which is the wrong date.

If I replace the liquid line with just `{{ meta }}` it outputs:

```
{"source_url"=>"http://vdocs-jg/forms/goodlife/standard.html?__launch_signing__=true&amp;customer_name=John%20Doe&amp;gender__male=true&amp;birth_date_DAY=8&amp;birth_date_MONTH=8&amp;birth_date_YEAR=1988&amp;address=675%20Hermione%20Street&amp;city=Lawrencetown&amp;state_id=MA&amp;postal=01823&amp;ctn=4136743582&amp;business_phone=4156328553&amp;business_extension=93&amp;drivers_license=TWACI2345&amp;email=me@me.com&amp;email_okay=true&amp;employer_name=Southwest%20Electric&amp;employer_phone=4032453564&amp;emergency_contact=Gerald&amp;emergency_phone=4564244543&amp;referred_by=Steve%20Murphy&amp;referred_number=546642",
"source_type"=>"html",
"terminal_lang"=>"en",
"dba"=>"wirelesswave",
"country"=>"CA",
"terminal_id"=>2,
"contract_lang"=>"en",
"contract_parser"=>"web_form",
"contract_with"=>"carrier",
"carrier"=>"goodlife",
"customer_name"=>"John Doe",
"gender"=>"male",
"birth_date"=>"19880808",
"contract_template"=>"goodlife_standard_1",
"industry_type"=>"cellular",
"pos_status"=>"unknown",
"tran_id"=>"20110816161001_4136743582"}
```

(formatted for readability, some info removed)

As you can see, birth_date is "19880808" which is the value my tests are expecting. And even in the source_url where we are deriving that date from it is set correctly (`birth_date_DAY=8&amp;birth_date_MONTH=8&amp;birth_date_YEAR=1988`)

Additionally some nearby lines

```
    <td class="title">Address</td>
    <td>{{ meta/address }}</td>
    <td class="title">City</td>
    <td>{{ meta/city }}</td>
```

are behaving correctly.

Why is Liquid putting out this seemingly random date? Could this be seeded from somewhere else?

Comment: This code is from a project that I'm not 100% familiar with so I'm still looking around for how the Liquid is getting its definition for `date:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`19880808` is date in Unix format. i.e. this is not 1988-08-08, this is 1970-08-18 (or 19 in +3 timezone).

```
$  ~  irb
2.1.0 :001 > Time.at(19880808)
 => 1970-08-19 05:26:48 +0300
```

If you want to show `19880808` as `1988-08-08` you should parse in before use `Date#strptime` method and after that convert it to your Date format.

Comment: This was such an obvious answer, I feel stupid for not realizing this :(. Now I need to figure out where it's being set in `meta` or if I can change the way Liquid parses it.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers#extending-liquid) section? Seems like you need to implement filter to parse and format date in your format.

Comment: The error is stemming from a change that was made to some homebrew date parsing, which will need to be fixed regardless. Thanks though! That link is very helpful.